# In R; add values to existing column based on values of 2 columns being equal otherwise blank

Tags: r

I am a R numpty so please help. I have a csv table (Combined1) with 13 columns (0.5million rows). I have an empty column at the end 'Wildtype_TYPE' which I want to populate with values from col 'TYPE.x' only if the values from col 'TYPE.x' match with those from col 'TYPE.y'. I have tried this already:

```
Combined1[, "Wildtype_TYPE" := "TYPE.x"["TYPE.x" == "TYPE.y"]
```

and mutate and ifelse but I can't get it to work. I get printed output with the row number and FALSE etc.
Any help much appreciated. Thanks.

I would like it to end up like this:

```
TYPE.x    TYPE.y    Wildtype_TYPE
  A         C
  G         G           G
  C         C           C
  T         G
    USE CHROM.x POS.x   REF.x   TYPE.x  QUAL.x  CHROM.y POS.y   REF.y   TYPE.y  QUAL.y  Wildtype_TYPE
1   gi|339957448|gb|AENI01001139.1|14433    gi|339957448|gb|AENI01001139.1| 14433   G   G   41.77   gi|339957448|gb|AENI01001139.1| 14433   G   NA  41.77    
2   gi|339957448|gb|AENI01001139.1|14471    gi|339957448|gb|AENI01001139.1| 14471   T   C   195.77  gi|339957448|gb|AENI01001139.1| 14471   T   C   183.77   
3   gi|339957448|gb|AENI01001139.1|14474    gi|339957448|gb|AENI01001139.1| 14474   C   T   1226.77 gi|339957448|gb|AENI01001139.1| 14474   C   T   899.84
```

Comment: I would like col Wildtype_TYPE to be filled with values from TYPE.x if TYPE.x values match TYPE.y values, and if not then blank. As below:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A reproductible exemple would be better, but you should try something along:

```
Combined1[ Combined1$TYPE.x ==  Combined1$TYPE.y,'Wildtype_TYPE'] <-  Combined1[ Combined1$TYPE.x ==  Combined1$TYPE.y, 'TYPE.x']
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Looks like it should work, but I am getting this error 'missing values are not allowed in subscripted assignments of data frames', presumably because I have NAs in the column. I will remove the NAs and try again.

Comment: I have now removed the NAs so don't get error message and the script works. However instead of getting the values from the TYPE.x column e.g A, G, C in the Wildtype_TYPE column I get numbers. I Any further help appreciated.

Comment: Hi Matthieu P. Thanks for the answer, it did work in the end.